# Calculate sensor unique address with a 8 position DIP Switch

Tags: switch

I have a large amount of sensor boards that I need to be able to configure setting unique addresses. Each sensor is attached to it's own arduino, I'm using a 8 position DIP switch for setting the address.

I have tried diferent approaches. When I switch On and OFF I get random values. I understood that I would be able to get up to 255 possible positions, but without being able to get the proper byte data I would have to manually code each possibility, which seems wrong.

Schematic :

[image]

Code

```
#include "DipSwitchI2C.h"

DipSwitchI2C::DipSwitchI2C(int address)
{
    _address = address;
}

void DipSwitchI2C::begin()
{
    Wire.begin();
}

int DipSwitchI2C::read()
{
    unsigned int address = 0;
    unsigned int value = 0;

    Wire.requestFrom(_address, 1);
    if (Wire.available())
    {
        value = Wire.read();
    }
    Wire.endTransmission();

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        address += (value & (1<<i)) > 0;
    }

    return address;
}
```

Comment: A 8 position DIP switch can have 256 positions. And you are just calculating the sum of bits.

Comment: First of all, you must be sure that the _address has the right i2c address of the pcf8574, then you can do a Wire.requestFrom(_address,1) and a return(Wire.read()). That's all, two lines, nothing else.

Comment: it is unclear what this means .... `without being able to get the proper byte data`

Comment: since you have only one sensor board on any given Arduino, why do you need a unique address on the sensor board?

Comment: determine what is the value of  `Wire.read()` at this line `value = Wire.read();` .... you may be surprised

Comment: @jsotola I have network of sensors connected by rs485. I need to be able to ask the sensor reading for every arduino from a master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jsotola noted the solution was simple:

```
int DipSwitchI2C::read()
{
    unsigned int address = 1;

    Wire.requestFrom(_address, 1);
    if (Wire.available())
    {
        address = Wire.read();
    }
    Wire.endTransmission();

    return address;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your switches are on pins 2-9 on an UNO.  Change pins to match what you actually have.

```
byte addressVal = 0;
for(int i = 2: i<10; i++){
    addressVal <<= 1;
    addressVal += digitalRead(i);
}
```

This will check each switch and add a 1 to the end of the byte.  On each iteration it shifts the contents of that byte 1 place to the left.  After it reads all the pins you have a byte with a value 0 to 255 depending on the states of the pins.

Comment: The switches are connected to the arduino by a PCF8574 multiplexer not directly to the pins.

Comment: Well then replace the digitalRead command with whatever command you use to read a pin from the multiplexer.